# MySQL alias for Subquery doesnt work

Tags: mysql, alias

I write this code into my MySQL Terminal, but MySQL responses with 
"ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.SD_ID' in 'on clause'"

I dont know why it doesnt understand my alias.

```
SELECT  t.TBL_NAME              AS 'TABLE',
t.TBL_TYPE                      AS 'TYPE',
a.COLUMN_NAME                   AS 'COLUMN_NAME',
a.TYPE_NAME                     AS 'TYPE'
   FROM TBLS t
   JOIN
       (SELECT c.TYPE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.CD_ID
           FROM COLUMNS_V2 c, SDS s
           WHERE c.CD_ID = s.CD_ID) a
   ON t.SD_ID = a.SD_ID
WHERE t.TBL_TYPE = 'MANAGED_TABLE'
ORDER BY b.TBL_NAME, b.INTEGER_IDX;
```

I query this in on MySQL on a Ubuntu System.

Comment: You forgot to add to your select s.SD_ID or c.SD_ID in the subquery

Comment: Why `FROM COLUMNS_V2 c, SDS s`? Comma-separated joins were made redundant in 1992. That was before MySQL even existed. Use explicit ANSI joins instead (`FROM COLUMNS_V2 c JOIN SDS s ON ...`).

Comment: And why do you join with `SDS` at all? You are only selecting values of `COLUMNS_V2` in the subquery. What is the purpose of the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `SD_ID` column inside `subquery`. Check the commented line below. Also prefer ANSI styled join:

```
SELECT  
 t.TBL_NAME    AS 'TABLE',
 t.TBL_TYPE    AS 'TYPE',
 a.COLUMN_NAME AS 'COLUMN_NAME',
 a.TYPE_NAME   AS 'TYPE'
FROM TBLS t
  INNER JOIN
     (SELECT c.TYPE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.CD_ID -- include either c.SD_ID or s.SD_ID
      FROM COLUMNS_V2 c 
      inner join SDS s
      on c.CD_ID = s.CD_ID
     ) a
   ON t.SD_ID = a.SD_ID
WHERE t.TBL_TYPE = 'MANAGED_TABLE'
ORDER BY b.TBL_NAME, b.INTEGER_IDX;
```